# XAMMP only working on local host

Tags: windows, xampp

I was wondering why my XAMPP is only working for my local host, and not my domain.

I use DYNU.COM to point the domain to my VPS, and according to http://dnscheck.pingdom.com There are no errors.

How do i go from here to host something on the domain with the VPS?

I've tried binding, disabling firewall, but it's not doing anything at all.

I've already tried https://hotcomm.com/FAQ/FAQ_staticIPXP.asp , but it did not make any difference, I was able to locally access my IP, and see the content, but not from the outside.

I don't have access to the router since it is a VPS, but port 80 etc, should be open?

I'm pretty desperate at this point. If i'm missing information, I'll add it right into the OP.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is build for programming, not for public hosting, since it is "quick and dirty" and not secure.

Try to find a cheap hoster with PHP/MySQL and have much less trouble.

If you realy want to show your XAMPP site to the public internet (maybe for your customers) then look for Porforwarding on your router an the right exceptions in your windows firewall (Port 80 ingoing).

"Normaly" your router should block all your traffic from outside. You also need an static (private) ip in your network which the router must know for the port forwaring (Port 80 outside to port 80 at your PC).

Comment: Problem is that i need specific programs for my hosting, and so something like namecheap shared hosting doesn't fullfill my needs. I'm wondering what would be a better solution to use on a Windows VPS? Any recommendations to use instead of XAMPP?